# Svelte animation blocks transition

Tags: svelte, svelte-store, svelte-transition

I have a component that is build like this

```html
<ul class="space-y-3 flex-col items-end justify-end absolute bottom-6 left-6 right-6 overflow-hidden">
    {#each $chatDisplayQueue as chatEvent (chatEvent.id)}
        <div in:fly={{y:150,duration: 200}} out:fade={{duration: 200}} animate:flip={{duration: 200}}>
            <ChatMessage event={chatEvent}/>
        </div>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Notice i have both a transition and an animation.
The in transition works but, the out transition does not work if the flip animation is on there :/
Is there a way to do this properly so that both transitions and the animation works?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both animation already work, but at the same time.

When you add a delay (`animation:flip={{ delay:200 }}`) you're able to see the fade.

```
let delay = 0
function addItem() {
  delay = 0;
  ...
}
function removeItem() {
  delay = 200;
  ...
}
</script>

...
<div animation:flip={{ delay }}>...
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/52a1d8564bfa4c9da6dc9c3a570109ed?version=3.14.1
(credits to isarikaya for most this repl)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you want something like this:

```js
<script>
    import {flip} from 'svelte/animate';
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    let horizontal = false;
  let next = 1;
    let list = [];
    const addItem = () => list = [next++, ...list];
    const removeItem = number => list = list.filter(n => n !== number);
    const options = {};
</script>

<label>
  Horizontal
  <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={horizontal} />
</label>
<button on:click={addItem}>Add</button>
{#each list as n (n)}
  <div transition:fly="{{ y: 200, duration: 2000 }}" animate:flip={options} class:horizontal class="container">
      <button on:click={() => removeItem(n)}>{n}</button>
  </div>
 {/each}

<style>
    .container {
        width: fit-content; /* a fix */
    }
    .horizontal {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

source: [url](https://svelte.dev/repl/b4cceba5e8a14e379e1b07f47b792eef?version=3.14.1)